# "moindres que" vs " moins que"

Tags: choix-de-mot

How can one decide when to use "moindres que" or " moins que"?

Examples:

1. [Les ventes de Tiffany baissent **moins que** prévu au 3e trimestre](https://www.reuters.com/article/tiffany-resultats-idFRKBN2841RX) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122215251if_/https://www.reuters.com/article/tiffany-resultats-idFRKBN2841RX)).
2. [Coronavirus : Les livraisons de vaccin AstraZeneca/Oxford **moindres que** prévues en Europe](https://www.20minutes.fr/monde/2959587-20210122-coronoavirus-livraisons-vaccin-astrazenecaoxford-moindres-prevues-europe) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122215314/https://www.20minutes.fr/monde/2959587-20210122-coronoavirus-livraisons-vaccin-astrazenecaoxford-moindres-prevues-europe)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Moins" is an adverb. It means "less".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moins)) I. − Adv. de quantité
> A. − Compar. d'infériorité
>
> 1. [Dans un système compar., exprime une qualité ou une intensité inférieure, soit à cette même qualité ou intensité chez un autre être ou objet, soit à une autre qualité ou intensité]
>    a) [Le morphème compar., corrélatif de moins (mais qui peut être sous-entendu) est la conj. que] Moins... (que)

"Moindre" is an adjective only. It means "smaller".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moindre)) I. − [Compar. de supériorité de petit]
> A. − [En parlant d'une chose abstr., d'une notion générale mais quantifiable] Plus petit (en étendue, en quantité, en importance). Synon. inférieur.

In consequence of their different grammatical nature, as usual you use "moins" (adverb) to modify a verb, an adjective or another adverb, and you use "moindre" (adjective) to modify a noun (must be an abstract noun).

- Il **parlent** moins dans la journée.
- Le soleil est moins **chaud** en cette saison.
- Ça se fait moins **facilement** sans une machine.

- Les **frais** de transport sont moindres. (*Spending for transportation is smaller. —  attribut de « frais »*)

When you want to make a comparison and that for that purpose you use "que" nothing changes.

- Ils **parlent** moins que l'année dernière.
- Le soleil est chaud mais moins chaud qu'hier (*ellipsis: moins qu'hier*).
- Ça se fait moins **facilement** qu'avec cette nouvelle machine.

- Les **retards** sont moindres qu'en période de vacances.

---

- Les ventes de Tiffany **baissent** moins que prévu au 3e trimestre (*…sales **are dropping less** than expected*)
- Coronavirus : Les **livraisons** de vaccin AstraZeneca/Oxford (sont) moindres que prévues en Europe (***deliveries** are **less important** than expected — there is an ellipsis of the verb form "sont"; "moindre" is "attribut du sujet « livraisons »"*)